# is there a solution to save on one file by multiple app in same time in C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I have a program that runs under the internal network
So several copies of this program are executed simultaneously and all of them are saved and restored on one file.
How do I do this?
If the file is xls, it gives an error.
How does my program write to a file at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding well your question, I don't think you can write from several sources to a same file, see [race condition: file system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition#File_systems), but I believe you can simulate this behavior by having several files (one for each instance of these application) and then every certain time update your main file with the gathered data.

Answer (score 0):

At the same time is a bad idea ->

[Racecondition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition), use something which is [ACID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID) (Database f.e.) to avoid such problems. If it has to be a file use some mutual exclusion mechanism like [semaphores](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semaphore_(programming)) [(semaphores in .net)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.semaphore?view=net-5.0).